# RAND_bytes not invoking though setting a RAND_set_rand_method()?

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, fips

Even though we set currentMethod.bytes with local function to generate     random numbers, the `RAND_bytes` is not invoking. After we set `RAND_set_rand_method(&cuurentMethod)`.

Here I attached link [https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/test/sm2_internal_test.c]  which I already tried.

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char rand[16];
    int ret;
    RAND_METHOD *oldMethod,currentMethod,*temp;
    oldMethod = RAND_get_rand_method();/*getting default method*/
    currentMethod = *oldMethod;
    currentMethod.bytes = local_function_rand;

    if((ret = RAND_set_rand_method(&currentMethod))!= 1)
        return 0; 

   /* Now we are printing both address of local_function_method_rand() and 
   temp->bytes , those address are same after getting. */

   temp = RAND_get_rand_method();

   /* after we are comparing with RAND_SSLeay() function , to find default or not*/

   if((ret = RAND_bytes(rand,16)) != 1)
       return 0;
   return 1;
}
```

Expecting result is our local function should invoke. Also, to invoke `RAND_bytes()` is it required to set fips mode in Linux system?

Comment: Include a [mcve] in the body of your question?

Comment: Also `RAND_set_rand_method()` doesn't return anything... at least not with OpenSSL 1.1.1. Did it change prototypes to return a value at some point in time before or after that version?

Comment: Plus you seem to have your return values from `main()` backwards.. `0`/`EXIT_SUCCESS` on success, `EXIT_FAILURE` (Usually defined as 1) on error...

Comment: Thank you for reply, In OpenSSL v2.1.0 RAND_set_rand_method() is return 
      the
       value(https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) and could you 
       please let me know if any logs prints which related to    
       local_function_rand() on console.

Comment: There's no such version of OpenSSL...

Comment: Interestingly, looking at the source, the function *does* return an int, but the documentation says otherwise.

Comment: yeah shawn, some of the OpenSSL man pages they  return void and some of pages they given return type int ,like  as you mentioned.But in OpenSSL 1.0.2g also function return type is int only in rand.h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After cleaning up and minimizing your test program and filling in the missing parts:

```
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int local_function_rand(unsigned char *buf, int num) {
  printf("in local_function_rand(); requested %d bytes\n", num);
  memset(buf, 4, num); // RFC 1149.5 standard random number
  return 1;
}

int main(void) {
  unsigned char rand[16];
  RAND_METHOD currentMethod = {.bytes = local_function_rand};
  RAND_set_rand_method(&currentMethod);

  if (RAND_bytes(rand, sizeof rand) != 1) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

and running it (With OpenSSL 1.1.1):

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra rand.c -lcrypto
$ ./a.out
in local_function_rand(); requested 16 bytes
```

it works as expected; the user-supplied function is being called by `RAND_bytes()`. If you're getting different results from your code, there's probably a problem in the bits you didn't include in your question.

Comment: Thank you Shawn, it working fine when i execute with simple example with OpenSSL(1.0.2g).